# Como fazer Paginação usando PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, paginação

Tenho uma query simples que traz os resultados e monta uma tabela e queria que depois da tabela viesse uma paginação: (), mas não sei como fazer.

A consulta está assim:

```
$nome=$_GET['nome'];
if($nome!=''){
    $filtronome = " WHERE nome LIKE '%{$nome}%' ";
}else{
    $filtronome = "";
}
$query = ("SELECT * FROM lancamentos ".$filtronome);
$db -> setQuery($query);
$results = $db -> loadObjectList();

echo '<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Nome</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
foreach($results as $r){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$r->id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$r->nome.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>'
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Para paginar basta trabalhar com `offset`  e `limit`
Exp:
`pagina 1 - (01-10): offset=0, limit=10;`
`pagina 2 - (11-20) offset=10, limit=10;`

Comment: Complementando, pode ainda criar uma lógica onde primeiro verifica quantos elementos existem na tabela usando `count(*)` e dividir com a quantidade de elementos que quer em cada pagina para saber quantas paginas vão existir

Comment: Leandro, pus 3 links como referência, mas se pesquisar por "paginação" no site vai encontrar vários outros exemplos;

Comment: show, vou dar uma lida, obrigado!